# Passing variable to .animate() function JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, variables, if-statement, jquery-animate

Below I have a function that animates a div (`container`) either to the left or the right depending on whether one variable (`nextItem`) is larger than the other (`currentItemRel`).

The problem I am having is using the `distance` variable in the `.animate()` function.

How can I pass this variable? Currently my JavaScript is breaking so any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou

```
var distance = (nextItem - currentItemRel) * 1260;

            if (nextItem > currentItemRel)
            {

                $('#container').animate({ left: -=distance }, 1200);

            } else if (nextItem < currentItemRel)
            {
                $('#container').animate({ left: +=distance }, 1200);
            };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the += and -= modifier for the jquery animate function, has to be parsed as a string.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNbX4/)

Comment: I was just thinking outside of the box and putting it as a variable. Thanks, the fiddle was great!